# Wanting to ditch MTKView.currentRenderPassDescriptor

Tags: metal, metalkit

I have an occasional issue with my `MTKView` renderer stalling on obtaining a `currentRenderPassDescriptor` for 1.0s.  According to the docs, this is either due the view's device not being set (it is) or there are no drawables available.

If there are no drawables available, I don't see a means of just immediately bailing or skipping that video frame.  The render loop will stall for 1.0s.

**Is there a workaround for this?**. Any help would be appreciated.

My workflow is a bunch of kernel shader work then one final vertex shader.  I could do the drawing of the final shader onto my own texture (instead of using the `currentPassDescriptor`), then hoodwink that texture into the view's `currentDrawable` -- but in the obtaining of that drawable we're back to the same stalling situation.

Should I get rid of `MTKView` entirely and fall back to using a `CAMetalLayer` instead?  Again, I suspect the same stalling issues will arise.  Is there a way to set the `maximumDrawableCount` on an `MTKView` like there is on `CAMetalLayer`?

I'm a little baffled as, according the Metal System Trace, my work is invariably completed under 5.0ms per frame on an iMac 2015 R9 M395.

Comment: How frequently are you trying to draw to screen? Are you sure you aren't holding strong references to drawables or their textures longer than needed?

Comment: Drawing @ 60fps.  No strong references are being held to drawables at all, nor textures.  The thing will chug along for up to 2-3 minutes without issue.  I'll try everything in my power to interrupt it -- including a 1s usleep() call on the main thread -- to no avail. Run it a second time and it dies within a few seconds.  GPU memory stays at a respectable 75%.  Something about the cadence of the draw calls is afoot.

Comment: Four HD movies playing to four MTKViews tiled onto one large window -- ie. backed by one CAMetalLayer (and thusly, one set of shared drawables).  In hindsight, this is a really bad idea.  Broke that up into 4 separate windows and 4 sets of drawables.  Comments, anyone?